# How to fetch data from MySQL using mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch MySQL data using below code, but it seems have some mistake. Can anyone help please. Thank you!

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myusername", "mypassword", "mydb") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$userRow = mysql_fetch_array($res);

echo $userRow["user_firstname"];
?>
```

Comment: Change this line `mysql_fetch_array($res);` to `mysqli_fetch_array($res);` u can't mix `mysql` with `mysqli`.

Comment: Thank you @Mario Problem Solved!

Comment: Great to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Mario

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myusername", "mypassword", "mydb") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=2";
$res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$userRow = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

echo $userRow["user_firstname"];
?>
```